# Error while trying to run project, Access is Denied

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I have ran my windows forms application. I am on a .net framework of 4. every time i try to hit start I am getting this error

[image: Error Message].

I have tried giving myself a new signing certificate, this has not worked, I have tried unchecking the clickonce manifest, I have unchecked sign the assembly with my strong name key file. I do not know what's going on.

What will work, every once in a while I can clean and rebuild and sometimes the application will work and then after I fix something on it and retry to run, it gets a access denied error.

Comment: I would try creating a new project and importing each item from the old one and see whether that new project works properly. I also wouldn't be storing projects on the desktop.

Comment: The project is like my utility / testing stuff. Thats why it is on my desktop right now. Started a new project still a windows app and didn't even add any code, i got a access is denied.

Comment: Maybe a virus scanner that blocks the file? You could exclude the projects folder from scans.

Comment: I think that is exactly what it is. I looked into windows defender and saw that it is blocking the file from opening. so sometimes it runs and others it does not.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @VDWWD this was my solution. My application was getting blocked by windows defender. I am asking my tech team to add the folder of my solution to an exclusion list so that windows defender does not check for it.

Thanks for the help folks!!